# Use RPC over HTTP pragmatically

Tags: c#, .net, outlook, exchangewebservices

Scenario: My company's Exchange server can be accessed from the internet without vpn only by outlook. This is because of the 'outlook anywhere' functionality. From what I have understood, it connects to a proxy server which in turn accesses the mail server.

What I have: A .net application that downloads attachments from a folder on my mail, sends mails based on the downloaded information.

What I would like to do: I want to know if there is any way I can make the application that can make use of the outlook anywhere functionality.  If its possible, where should I start?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EWS uses straight HTTP/HTTPS. Are you trying to programmatically configure a new profile?

Comment: No, I already have a profile. I'm just trying to access the mailbox.

Comment: Once you have a configured profile, you should be able to use whether it is ROH or RPC. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Maybe I don't fully understand what a profile is. I'll update the question.

Comment: If you have Outlook installed, add a reference to the Outlook Object Model library and use OOM to access any folders, messages and attachments. Start at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee861520(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: but thats the thing, I do not want it to be dependent on outlook.

Comment: Then you need to use straight EWS. MS provides managed EWS library - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd633626(v=exchg.80).aspx